# Back click listener for Google Places Address Search (AutocompleteSupportFragment)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places

[image]Is there a way to capture the back button click listener from Google Places Address Search (AutocompleteSupportFragment)

```
  val btnBackClick =
            autocompleteFragment?.view?.findViewById(R.id.places_autocomplete_back_button) as androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton

        btnBackClick.setOnClickListener {
            Log.e("AutoComplete", "Address Search Back")
        }
```

Tried this leading to crash  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Places must be initialized."

Comment: Have you initialized Places sdk? like `Places.initialize(mContext, "your key")`

Comment: Yes of course, I have initialized them before accessing it but still getting the same

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to get the back button the same way you did on my end, but you are right, that View returns `null` even though it apparently exists: `R.id.places_autocomplete_back_button`.

**Update:** At the moment it is not currently possible to get this View, so I recommend you file a feature request for this in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188846&template=787414) in case Google Engineers are able to consider adding this capability.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @evan. First of all I posted in Google Issue tracker only. Based on the reply from them I posted here in StackOverflow. Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145943299

Comment: Thanks @Damodaran let me get back to you once I have an update on this.

Comment: Sure! Note that I'm still working on this. I'll get back to you next week!

Comment: @Damodaran Heya, update: getting the "back" of the Autocomplete search box is not currently possible. The best course of action here is that you submit a FR for this in Google's issue tracker, instead of a bug like you did previously. I'm afraid that's all we can do about this. Will update my answer accordingly. Good luck friend! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I couldn't get a reference through neither the back button of the AutocompleteSupportFragment / onBackPressed listener / onBackPressedDispatcher from the activity, so I went on and used the error status instead.

```
// Assuming "autocompleteFragment" is the view name in your XML file
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocompleteFragment) as AutocompleteSupportFragment
// ... 

fragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener {
    override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {
        // Handle the result like usual
    }
    override fun onError(status: Status) {
        // Check if the user tapped the back button
        if (status == Status.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Do what you want to do when back button is pressed
        }
    }
}
```

Technically a workaround, but it does capture the back button flow.